# Error when installing remote access role: There may be a version mismatch between this computer and the destination server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

I am getting an error when I attempt to select the Remote Access role on a Windows 2016 Server.  I have been unable to find this error mentioned anywhere.   I am installing the role on the local server, so I don't understand the error.

[image: Windows server error]

Comment: Only info I found is to try a DISM /online /cleanup-image /CheckHealth, and a /RestoreHealth after if it found a error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it very easy.
Return to previous page (x2), and then:
On the Select installation type page, ensure that Role-based or feature-based installation option is selected and click Next.
On the Select destination server page, ensure that the local server is selected and click Next.
Again on the Server Roles page, select Remote Access checkbox and click Next.
It should work now!

Comment: Strangely just backing up and clicking next again let it install.  Nothing changed in the selections, just backed up and did it again.  Thanks.    before I had closed the window and started over each time, which produced the error every time.